# Bing Maps Credentials Don't Exist?

Tags: c#, wpf, soap, bing-maps

I'm messing about with the Bing Maps WPF control and SOAP services, trying to reverse geocode a point. I tried to implement some code from [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79123/Sample-WPF-Application-Consuming-Bing-Maps-Web-Ser), specifically this block of code:

```
private string ReverseGeocodePoint(string locationString)
          {
              string results = "";
              ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();

              // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
              reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
              reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

              // Set the point to use to find a matching address
              GeocodeService.Location point = new GeocodeService.Location();
              string[] digits = locationString.Split(';');

              point.Latitude = double.Parse(digits[0].Trim());
              point.Longitude = double.Parse(digits[1].Trim());

              reverseGeocodeRequest.Location = point;

              // Make the reverse geocode request
              GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient();
              GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.ReverseGeocode(reverseGeocodeRequest);

              if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
                  results = geocodeResponse.Results[0].DisplayName;
              else
                  results = "No Results found";

              return results;
          }
```

However, when I try to implement it, I'm being told: `Error: The type or namespace name 'Credentials' does not exist in the namespace 'GeocodeTest.GeocodeService' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` This error occurs on the line:

```
reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
```

Curious, I decided to take a look at the service reference through the object browser. Apparently, my `GeocodeService` doesn't even have a `Credentials` member. So now the question is:

- **Should I add the member myself? If so, how would I do this?**
- **If not, what alternatives to do have in terms of providing credentials?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Credentials` namespace/type doesn't exist for the service reference `GeocodeText.GeocodeService`. Instead, you have to use the `Credentials` from the Bing Maps WPF Control. The statement would look like so:

```
reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Credentials();
```